# Kali Linux no config.txt on RPI 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux

I downloaded the Img file from their website and after imaging with win32diskimager there is no config.txt. I need it because my screen is 5" 800x480 and I need to input that in config.txt. It is currently running fine on my 72" TV but I've explore every directory and still no config.txt

Comment: If its not in the root directory where it should be then try making one.

Comment: Make a config.txt?

Comment: Yes, that's a general rule of thumb, if the file is not there put it there.